# Write a Function that sequentially adds data from differernt columns

Tags: r, function

I have a simplified data frame that looks like this:

```
A<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
B<-c(2,3,4,5,6)
C<-c(3,4,5,6,7)
D<-c(4,5,6,7,8)
DF<-data.frame(A,B,C,D)
```

I would like to write a function in R that (starting with the first column) reads in two columns at a time, finds the overlap, and creates a new complete series. Then loops this function to read in the next column, and so on...

So the work flow would be something like

```
Read in columns A and B, find the match and stitch together
Result is new variable X= 1,2,3,4,5,6

Read in new variable X and column C, find the match and stitch together
Result is new variable X= 1,2,3,4,5,6,7

Read in new variable X and column D, find match and stitch together
Result is new variable X= 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
```

As of now, I have a more complex function given to me in a separate thread in the format of fun(Col_1, Col_2), but I'm having problems looping it over the entire data frame and I'm hoping to work out that aspect here.

Comment: If I consider all at the same time, I will end up with the same result. Am I missing something?

Comment: No, I wrote this question this way because I already have a function I would like to use, but the function only compares two columns at a time. I'm just not sure how to implement this function over several columns worth of data, similar to the above simplified example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for `Reduce()`. And the operation you are performing is a union. This can be some with

```
Reduce(union, DF)
```

here treating the data.frame `DF` like a list of vectors which is essentially what you are doing.

Comment: Great answer, but I have a (much more complicated) function that I'd like to work with, and this is just a simplified version of my problem. So I'm looking for an answer that loops a function over each successive column as with the above workflow, that I can then apply to my more complex function

Comment: @Vinterwoo that's basically what `Reduce` does. I don't see why this wouldn't work with other functions. If it works with your provided sample data, then I assume the answer is correct. Perhaps it would be helpful to provide a more representative example.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. But I'm a little confused how to apply Reduce to a function. The function I would like to apply this example to is in the format "functionX(A,B)"- so it only looks at two columns at a time. I'm not sure what the code would look like.  From reading about Reduce, I don't think "Reduce(functionX(A,B),DF)" makes any sence

Comment: That exactly the type of function `Reduce` wants. It passes in two parameters. Of course it would just be `Reduce(functionX, DF)`